# Splitting out an array from a splatted object

Tags: powershell

Okay, so I've got a bit of code which calls another PS script from within a PS script, and passes in a couple of parameters: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$a1,$a2) &$script @($a1,$a2) } -ArgumentList @($scriptToRun,$p1,$p2) -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred`

The problem I'm experiencing however, is the receiving script is getting both $a1 & $a2 combined together in $args[0].  What I can't figure out as yet, is how do I split out the two array elements again?

Alternatively, how can I get them to pass correctly without the `@()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splatting isn't required here, so simply remove the `@()`:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
  param($script,$a1,$a2)
  & $script $a1 $a2
} -ArgumentList $scriptToRun,$p1,$p2 ...
```

The default behavior is to assign each argument from the argument list to the corresponding positional parameter in the parameter definition of the script block.

Or, if you want to use splatting, you need to do it like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
  param($script,$params)
  & $script @params
} -ArgumentList $scriptToRun,@($p1,$p2) ...
```

Comment: Running it as `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$a1,$a2) &$script @($a1,$a2) } -ArgumentList $scriptToRun,$p1,$p2 -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred`, the same thing occurs.  Even running it as `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$a1,$a2) &$script $a1,$a2 } -ArgumentList $scriptToRun,$p1,$p2 -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred` does the same thing.  I really have no idea how it is joining them.

Comment: I also tried: `$arguments = $p1,$p2
$params = $scriptToRun,$arguments
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$arguments) &$script $arguments } -ArgumentList $params -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred` for the same outcome.

Comment: In the script getting called, all I have is: `$parent = $args[0]
Write-Host $parent` and both values are getting written.

Comment: If you put a comma between arguments of a procedure or function call, they'll be passed as a single array argument. Or pass the parameters as an array to a single script block parameter and splat that parameter (`@arguments`) when invoking the other script. See updated answer.